# Does the mechanism of the Schmidt reaction involve a nitrene as an intermediate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Per the mechanism described [here](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/schmidt-reaction.shtm) the reaction does **not** involve *nitrene* as an intermediate.(EDIT-1---I initially thought the written mechanism described *so*, but as Zhe points out,I was wrong in my observation.)

But, can anybody shed some light on why the reaction does not involve *nitrene*; though it possibly can?

Comment: The mechanism is similar to that of a Curtius, for which there have been a lot more mechanistic studies. The reaction is thought to be more concerted, avoiding the intermediate nitrene (which although proposed, has never been observed).

Comment: I don't think the linked mechanism is quite correct

Comment: Nitrenes are higher energy species; why make one when you can have a concerted migration that presumably proceeds via a lower energy pathway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowhere in that link is there a nitrene formed. All steps are concerted, that is, you see that alkyl shift happens at the same time as dinitrogen fragmentation.

So indeed, nitrenes are not intermediates. I suspect that mechanistic studies have been done. You might consider looking at [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr60259a004?journalCode=chreay).